# Opening External Links in Phonegap with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am trying to link to an external link using the anchor tag like this:  [Google](https://www.google.com.sg/) .

In order to do that, i added this code in appDelegate.m(the code is from here: https://gist.github.com/2012253):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

But i am not still be able to link to Google... Am i doing something wrong? Need some help.

Comment: have you set the `ExtrernalHosts` property correctly?? is your url opening in the app??

Comment: the url is not opening in the app...how to set the externalhosts?

Comment: in your Cordova.plist file, for detail - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: firstly thanks.. what should the value for the string be? http or google.com? not sure abt it..

Comment: for ios, just google.com

Comment: then in the anchor tag, what should i put?

Comment: giving me this error: ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://www.google.com/'

Comment: when you open in plain text it should look like this `<key>ExternalHosts</key><array><string>google.com</string></array>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13419/discussion-between-lakesh-and-dhaval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `ExternalHosts` property in Cordova.plist file is properly set. ExternalHosts is an array of hosts that you are whitelisting so that it can be accessed from your application.

For google (http and https)

```
google.com
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

For example, check my demo application [here](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/ios-cordova-video/ios-cordova-video)

Comment: specify what the ExternalHosts needs to be... might be more helpful.. thats why...

Answer (score 0):

I have used that piece of code in MainViewController.m in cordova 1.7.0 cordova 1.9.0 and cordova 2.1.0 and it works pretty well. You just need to move that code to the correct file.